# How to keep the values of dropdown list when the form is submitted in php?

Tags: php, html

Here is the code i have written, Please do help me to solve this issue.

```
<select name="gender" id="gender">
                    <option value="M"<?php if(isset($_POST['gender'])=="M"){echo "selected='selected'";}?>>Male</option>
                    <option value="F"<?php if(isset($_POST['gender'])=="F"){echo "selected='selected'";}?>>Female</option>
                    <option value="O"<?php if(isset($_POST['gender'])=="O"){echo "selected='selected'";}?>>Other</option>
                    </select>
```

When i submit the form by selecting Male in dropdown list, it should keep the selected value till i change that in the next submission of form.

In the above code if i select the Male and submit the form, its showing me Others.

so please need a little help. 
Thanks in advance to those who would like to fix the issue.

Comment: You will need to provide more details, such as your current code, and a more in depth description

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be fast and better if you use below :-

```
<select name="gender">
<option value="Male" <?php echo (isset($_POST['gender'] && $_POST['gender'] == 'Male')?'selected="selected"':''; ?> >Male</option>
<option value="Female" <?php echo (isset($_POST['gender'] && $_POST['gender'] == 'Female')?'selected="selected"':''; ?> >Female</option>
<option value="Other" <?php echo (isset($_POST['gender'] && $_POST['gender'] == 'other')?'selected="selected"':''; ?> >Other</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you were looking for it then approve the answer

Comment: This answer is not working. There are errors and page is not loading due to errors

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have this :

```
<select name="gender">
  <option value="Male">Male</option>
  <option value="Female">Female</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Then in your submitted page, place that :

```
<select name="gender">
  <option value="Male" <?php if ($_POST['gender'] == 'Male') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >Male</option>
  <option value="Female" <?php if ($_POST['gender'] == 'Female') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >Female</option>
  <option value="Other" <?php if ($_POST['gender'] == 'Other') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >Other</option>
</select>
```

Comment: same code i have written, but its not working. exactly same, not even a single letter is missing.

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me too. The marked answer is not working

Comment: Its giving me `Undefined index: gender`

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
      <option value="M"<?php 
     if(isset($_POST['gender'])=="M")
     --------^^^^^^^^^^^^
    {echo "selected='selected'";}?>>Male</option>
```

try

```
<option value="M"<?php if((!empty($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender']=="M")
                      ------^^^^^^^^
   {echo "selected='selected'";}?>>Male</option>
```

Comment: i removed the isset function which the OP was using with comparison operator.

Comment: Yeah, I saw after reading it through once more. That would have a problem if `gender` wasn't set, though (notice in the middle of an option element). Essentially `if (!empty($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender'] == 'M')` is best.